# Creating fractals through computers

Tags: soft-question, math-software, fractals

What are some beginner softwares for creating fractals on computers?

Comment: Do you have any programming experience?

Comment: Also: [Mandelbulber](http://www.mandelbulber.com/).

Comment: Hmm.. well to be honest, I have never used it for fractals! Its been a long time since I wrote a program in some language... but some languages that I was comfortable with before happen to be C, some C++, VB.net, Java, etc.

Comment: I am looking for some online site that uses some s/w to create fractals to begin with! (I guess one can use Photoshop but I am yet to try it out)  Later, as time goes on, I could probably fine-tune some areas. I do not intend to get into this full-time but just to use it for relaxation.

Comment: Are you looking for a 2D or 3D fractal drawer? How much functionality do you want? Do you only want to draw fractals that are determined by points that are bounded under repeated iteration?

Comment: You can do it in the web with $\large\tt javaScript$. There are a [lot of tutorials in this site](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/).

Comment: There is also lots here: http://fractalfoundation.org/resources/fractal-software/

Comment: Myridium: Both. I just began experimenting with s/w so I keep it simple. I might want to do other kinds later.

Comment: I just got started with Mandelbulber and XaoS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you do not want to be bothered by specifics of the graphical representation - i.e. you do not want to explicitly code the graphics.

Then generally you can use pretty much the standard tools:
Mathematica, Matlab (not so sure about Maple).
If you can use Matlab then using Python with matplotlib should be pretty easy.

If you know how to write programs in C++ MathGL is worth a look for graphics.

Comment: I do not want to code the graphics rightaway but yeah, sometime in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The program [Fractal Stream](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~noonan/fstream.html) makes good images of fractals based on complex dynamical systems.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [program Mandel by Wolf Jung](http://www.mndynamics.com/indexm.html). It has many demos which are a good intruduction to theory. Source code is available.